# How to extract string between space and symbol '>'?

Tags: python, regex, string, delimiter

String 1:

```
 [impro:0,grp:00,time:0xac,magic:0x00ac] CAR<7:5>|BIKE<4:0>,orig:0x8c,new:0x97
```

String 2:

```
[impro:0,grp:00,time:0xbc,magic:0x00bc] CAKE<4:0>,orig:0x0d,new:0x17
```

In string 1, I want to extract `CAR<7:5` and `BIKE<4:0`,

In string 2, I want to extract `CAKE<4:0`

Any regex for this in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\w+<[^>]+`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rYna8D/1)

[image]

- **\w** matches any word character (equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
- **+** matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy).
- **<** matches the character **<**
- **[^>]** Match a single character not present in the list
- **+** matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `re.findall` here with the pattern `(\w+.*?)>`:

```py
inp = ["[impro:0,grp:00,time:0xac,magic:0x00ac] CAR<7:5>|BIKE<4:0>,orig:0x8c,new:0x97", "[impro:0,grp:00,time:0xbc,magic:0x00bc] CAKE<4:0>,orig:0x0d,new:0x17"]
for i in inp:
    matches = re.findall(r'(\w+<.*?)>', i)
    print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['CAR<7:5', 'BIKE<4:0']
['CAKE<4:0']
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, the BIKE part has no leading space but a pipe char.

A bit more precise match might be asserting either a space or pipe to the left, and match the digits separated by a colon and assert the > to the right.

```
(?<=[ |])[A-Z]+<\d+:\d+(?=>)
```

In parts, the pattern matches:

- `(?<=[ |])` Positive lookbehind, assert either a space or a pipe directly to the left
- `[A-Z]+` Match 1+ chars A-Z
- `<\d+:\d+` Match `<` and 1+ digits betqeen `:`
- `(?=>)` Positive lookahead, assert `>` directly to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BT6LgH/1)

Or the capture group variant:

```
(?:[ |])([A-Z]+<\d+:\d)>
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bCN5Sq/1)